# Нужно расположить изображения используя все свободное место

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть такой макет, верхнюю часть выполнил.
Как выполнить вторую, содержащую 12 изображений с помощью flexbox?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: src сами добавите - https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/poEZMOW

Comment: на grid - https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/jOMpgXL тоже заменить src